# WCF Restful services in VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, rest, wcf

Does anyone know of a good screencast, walkthrough or tutorial for creating WCF Restful services in VS 2010?

I found the starter kit, but this appears to be for .net 3.5 / VS 2008.??

Then i found via the extension gallery a WCF Restful services template for VS 2010... THis appears to be what i need, but i have no idea of where to start with it..

I would appreciate any feedback anyone has

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This is what helped me get started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/endpoint/getting-started-with-wcf-webhttp-services-in-net-4)

Answer (score 2):

Endpoint.TV on Channel9 just had a new entry by Ron Jacobs showing [The Canonical REST Service](https://web.archive.org/web/20210226155950/https://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/endpointtv-Cannonical-REST-Service/) - pretty good stuff.

Most of the contents and topics covered in the [Channel9 screen cast series](https://web.archive.org/web/20100724230219/http://channel9.msdn.com:80/tags/REST%20Starter%20Kit%20endpoint%20screencasts/) (by Endpoint.TV) on WCF REST is still valid even for WCF 4 with VS 2010: